# Como solucionar el error al cargar el cuadro de herramientas de SSIS

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al crear un proyecto de Integration Services en el Visual Studio comunity, no me carga el cuadro de herramientas de SSIS. Se pone negro y nada mas. Lo cierro y vuelvo a abrir y nada.

Comment: Edit: He podido hacer que aparezcan las herramientas abriendo un proyecto de Integration Services primero y luego abriendo otro, no se si es por la carga que realiza al abrir el proyecto pero funciona de esta manera. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo si hacer esto comentelo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que dar doble clic en el .dtsx del panel derecho 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego se mostrara el cuadro de herramientas de SSIS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Fácil, la solución parecerá tonta pero.

1. inicia un nuevo proyecto (aquí seguramente se verán las herramientas), luego entra ha herramientas>importar y exportar configuraciones.
2. selecciona exportar... y siguiente
3. marca todas las opciones ... siguiente
4. ubica una ruta que recuerdes y finalizar.

---

en tu proyecto donde no se ven las herramientas...

1. entra ha herramientas>importar y exportar configuraciones.
2. selecciona importar... y siguiente
3. ubica la ultima configuración que exportaste (caso anterior)
4. finalizar.
   Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me resultó a mi fue:

1. Clic derecho dentro del paquete
2. Seleccionar "SSIS Toolbox"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y listo!